# Present a ViewController when notification is taped

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to show a detail view controller when the user tap on on a local notification.
So far, I've this:

```
//AppDelegate.swift

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let id = userInfo["item_id"] as? Int {
        if let item = ItemsRepository.shared.getItem(id: id) {
            let vc = DetailTableViewController()
            vc.item = item
            let tabController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
            let navigationController = tabController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

This code generates an exception, for some reason:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

- Version 2

`

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let id = userInfo["item_id"] as? Int {
        if let item = ItemsRepository.shared.getItem(id: id) {
            let vc = DetailTableViewController()
            vc.item = item
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailView") as! DetailTableViewController
            vc.item = item
            window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

It kinda works, but the tabbar and the navigation controllers are no longer visible !

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: in which line your code broken ?

Comment: At the start of the AppDelegate File !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by following the screen flow on my storyboard file. Basically, I've instantiate my `Main.storyboard` and then each view controller that follow.
[image: storyboard]

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let id = userInfo["item_id"] as? Int {
        if let item = ItemsRepository.shared.getItem(id: id) {
            let dv = DetailTableViewController()
            dv.item = item
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let tabbar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeFeed") as! UITabBarController
            tabbar.selectedIndex = 0
            let nav = tabbar.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
            let main = nav.topViewController as! HomeCollectionViewController
            main.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetailSegue", sender: item)
            self.window?.rootViewController = tabbar
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `let vc = DetailTableViewController()`

Try this

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
```

Tell me if this works

Comment: `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`, impossible !. Do you mean `window?.rootViewController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`  ?

Comment: Yes, what i meant was instantiating the vc, through its storyboard id

Comment: It kinda works, but the problem is, the navigation controller and the tab bar are not visible

Comment: You want to open a particular controller, along with its previous ones intact no matter whichever the screen is, when you receive this notification, right?

Comment: I just want to show the desired view controller with its tabbar and navigation controller !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            let tabController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailView") as! DetailTableViewController
            vc.item = item
            window?.rootViewController = tabController
            tabController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The view is showing up without tabbar and navigation controller !

Comment: try remove this line             window?.rootViewController = tabController

Comment: same result.. !

Comment: tabController is rootViewXontroller ?

Comment: This is correct . is this working outside notification?